# DWORD64 if set to -1 gives 32 1s i.e. 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

Tags: c++, dword

C++ code (Visual studio started with devenv /useenv (x64) and isWOW64 is false)

```
DWORD64 check;

check = -1;
printf("value %u", check);
```

it prints the value 4294967295 i.e. 0x(32)f which is the same if i do it with simple DWORD in an x32 environment

**yes i know DWORD64 is unsigned __int64,** but shouldn't it be 0x(64)f ?

what did the assembler do there ? disassembling the code didn't help me much.

Comment: simple -1. Am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: ... and that's why you should consider using C++ streams instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You problem here lies in the `printf` format string. Using `%u` tells `printf` to print a 32 bits value. Hence, it uses only the first 32 bits of your `DWORD64`. To print all the 64 bits that has been pushed onto the stack, use `%llu` (for `unsigned long long`).

Note also that `DWORD64` cannot be `unsigned long`. On all Windows versions, even on Windows 64 bits, `long` is 32 bits.

See [LLP64 model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: Thank-you for the answer :) ... missed a very basic information

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) the `%u` format specification is of type `int`. This means that `printf` reads the value as `int`, which even on 64-bit platforms are still 32 bits.

Add a [size specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) of either `ll` or `I64`, so the format will be `%I64u`.

Comment: true, printf will require %llu

Answer (score 2):

It should be `-1LL` because `-1` is stored as a 32bit int